# Taylor-Formula in multidimensional analysis

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

We have $x=(x_0, y_0)$

$f(x+ζ) = \sum_{|α| \leq2} \frac{D^αf(x)}{α!} \cdot ζ^α $

How would the addeds from the sum look like? The α confuses me.

I understand the multiindex but still have trouble to write the addends from the sum.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you have $f\colon A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose $f$ is of class $C^2$ then - you ask for order 2. Take $(x_0,y_0) \in A$ and a vector $\zeta = (\zeta_1,\zeta_2)$ such that $(x_0+\zeta_1,y_0+\zeta_2) \in A$. Then the Taylor polynomial of order 2 of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ is 
$$f(x_0,y_0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}_{|(x_0,y_0)}\zeta_1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}_{|(x_0,y_0)}\zeta_2+\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}_{|(x_0,y_0)}\zeta_1^2 +2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}_{|(x_0,y_0)} \zeta_1 \zeta_2 + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}_{|(x_0,y_0)} \zeta_2^2\bigg)$$

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this form 
$$f(x+ζ) = \sum_{|α| \leq2} \frac{D^αf(x)}{α!} \cdot ζ^α = \sum_{k=0}^{2}\sum_{|α| =k} \frac{D^αf(x)}{α!} \cdot ζ^α$$

Which is more easier to manage

since, you get,

$$f(x+ζ) = \\\underbrace{f(x)}_{k= 0}+\underbrace{\nabla f(x) \cdot ζ}_{k= 1}+\underbrace{\sum_{|α| =2} \frac{\partial_{x^2_1}^2f(x)}{2!0!} \cdot ζ^2_1+\frac{\partial_{x_1x_2}^2\partial_{}f(x)}{1!1!} \cdot ζ_1ζ_2+\frac{\partial_{x^2_2}^2\partial_{}f(x)}{2!0!} \cdot ζ^2_2}_{k= 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to take partial derivatives. I think it is easier with an example. Take a function $f(x^1,x^2)$, and $x_0=(x^1_0,x^2_0),\zeta=(\zeta^1,\zeta^2)$ Then
$$
f(x+\zeta)=f(x)+\left(\left.\frac{\partial }{\partial x^1}\right|_{x=x_0}f(x)\right)\zeta^1+\left(\left.\frac{\partial }{\partial x^2}\right|_{x=x_0}f(x)\right)\zeta^2+O(|\zeta|^2)
$$

That's the linear term, the square term will have the second derivatives, note the mixed derivative has to appear twice.

$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\left.\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial (x^1)^2}\right|_{x=x_0}f(x)\right)(\zeta^{1})^2+\left(\left.\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^1\partial x^2}\right|_{x=x_0}f(x)\right)\zeta^1\zeta^2+\frac{1}{2}\left(\left.\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial (x^2)^2}\right|_{x=x_0}f(x)\right)(\zeta^{2})^2
$$

All other terms are built similarly.

I guess what you are using is multindex notation where $\alpha=(\alpha^1,\alpha^2,\dots,\alpha^n)$. Then $\alpha!=\alpha^1!\cdots\alpha^n!$ and 
$$D^\alpha f=\frac{\partial^{\alpha^1+\alpha^2+\cdots+\alpha_n}}{\partial (x^1)^{\alpha^1}\partial (x^2)^{\alpha^2}\cdots \partial (x^n)^{\alpha^n}}f.$$
You see how the notation can easily get out of hand. Therefore the multindex is quite necessary.

It is interesting to note that for instance for the mixed term we get $(1,1)!=1$ therefore no $1/2$ factor appears in the mixed derivative (as shown above).

I am not sure I have made myself clear, I tried to use a notation as clear as possible; but I am not sure I succeed. Let me know if something is not clear

Comment: maybe its clearer if you write index as for example $a_1, a_2, ..$ instead of $a^1, a^2,..$

Comment: I am not sure, because the convention is to write them "upstairs" so as to have covariant and contravariant tensor with the indices in the right place. I know that in this case is not particularly relevant and I could have put the index downstairs. But I was completely annoyed each time a professor changed the notation with no apparent reason. (why wouldn't they introduce a proper notation at the very beginning).
Note that this makes $\zeta^\alpha=\zeta^{\alpha^1}\dots \zeta^{\alpha^n}$